# history.state not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

#### [The following code works in FF but not in Chrome:](http://jsfiddle.net/kqPBx/)

```
history.replaceState({ obj: 'pushed on' }, 'unused', '');

alert(history.state.obj);
```

Is there any way to get `history.state` to work in Chrome too?

Comment: FEI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history `history.state` is not supported in Chrome. But the object seems writeable, so you *could* assign the object to `history.state` manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js).

Comment: Especially the `History.getState()` method is important here.